# Merging duplicate columns while reading CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

Given a CSV file with duplicate column `A`, I need to read the file excluding the duplicate column -

```
 A       A       C
306     306     506
3238    3238    591
4159    4159    366
1847    1847    2898
```

Available alternative options include `usecols`, and `names`. However, in `Pandas version 0.24.1` we have `mangle_dupe_cols` parameter too, which if set to `False` should merge duplicate columns as mentioned in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

But, when I do so, I get ValueError-

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', mangle_dupe_cols=False, engine='python').head()
ValueError: Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet
```

Pandas version used for this problem - `0.24.1`

What are your views on this problem?

Comment: `df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]`

Comment: @user5173426 I have to merge `while reading`. I am well aware of the fact that there are various ways to remove duplicate after reading. I hope you get what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: You mean `A` `A.1` `C`?

Comment: @user5173426 My friend I just need `A` and `C`. Making `mangle_dupe_cols=True` by default gives `A A.1 C`

Comment: Pandas [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) says: "To prevent users from encountering this problem with duplicate data, a ValueError exception is raised if `mangle_dupe_cols != True`". It sounds like your problem does not have a solution.

Comment: @DYZ then what is the purpose of using `mangle_dupe_cols` if we can't merge dupes?

Comment: It is possible that you have an older version of Pandas installed.

Comment: Yes, @DYZ is right. I think you should remove them after reading. or create another CSV from it and read that one. ;)

Comment: Since I do not know pandas folks' intentions, I can only _speculate_ that they advertised and implemented the option, but it turned out to be dangerously misused and had to be disabled.

Comment: @DirtyBit 's answer is absolutely genius. Should be the highlighted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I check pandas github and found [ENH: Support mangle_dupe_cols=False in pd.read_csv()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262).

Unfortunately answer for [comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262#issuecomment-422572281) is [this comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262#issuecomment-422587138):

> What is the ETA on this issue?
>
> when / if a community pull request happens

One possible solution is read file twice:

```
c = pd.read_csv('some.csv', header=None, nrows=1).iloc[0]
#or
#with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
#  reader = csv.reader(f)
#  c = next(reader)

df = pd.read_csv('some.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)
df.columns = c
```

Comment: It seems like @DYZ is right. This argument is more of an advertisement! Thank you for the alternate suggestion but I just needed to understand the functioning of `mangle_dupe_cols` which still seems an open issue.